# Identifying a Bandai Namco plush character with chocolate hair, orange eyes, and blue dress

Tags: merchandise

This is a plush from the brand Bandai Namco. The character has chocolate hair, orange eyes, and wears a blue dress

[image]

Who is this character, and from what anime?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! While identification requests for [merchandise](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725) are technically ok (since it is a plush doll), this is off-topic due to the lack of additional details. You haven't provided any reason to believe the doll is from an anime or manga series

Comment: While the brand is mentioned, this is still very borderline on-topic. However, it'd be preferred if [more details can be provided](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4143/2516) by [edit]ing it, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**He is [Minori Watanabe](https://myanimelist.net/character/149249/Minori_Watanabe) from [*The iDOLM@STER SideM*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34915/The_iDOLMSTER_SideM)**, a spin-off from *The iDOLM@STER* series featuring male idols instead.

[image: the image character from the anime]

From [an Amazon listing, "Idol Master SideM Gift Plush Minori Watanabe"](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Master-SideM-Plush-Minori-Watanabe/dp/B074HQJ41Q)

[image: front-above view of the plush]

Comment: Nice find! I figured just the brand name wasn’t adequate details for it to be on-topic. To me, Bandi Namco is a broad criteria since it also covers video games :)